# AssetTagServiceUtil.getTagsCount() returns different count value based on user role for global tags

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created a plugin portlet which is scopeable and instanceable.

Since I have to `fetch tags related to Asset like Blogs in Global scope`, I have `made my plugin portlet scopeable so that I can pass scopeGroupId to AssetTagServiceUtil.getTagsCount() method.`

I am able to fetch tags based on scope. But for `global scope` the count value varies with different roles.

When I call

> AssetTagServiceUtil.getTagsCount(scopeGroupId, classNameId, tagName)
>   then it returns different count based on user's role.

For example say I have a Blog portlet in Global scope with tag "testglobaltag" then above call

> AssetTagServiceUtil.getTagsCount(scopeGroupId, 10007, "testglobaltag")

`returns count 1 for Admin user` and `for rest it returns count 2`. i.e `twice of the actual count.`

Note : 10007 is classNameId for Blogs.

Following is my liferay-portlet.xml entry to make my portlet scopable and instanceable.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>testassettagutilportlet</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <scopeable>true</scopeable>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>
            /js/main.js
        </footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>
            testassettagutilportlet-portlet
        </css-class-wrapper>
    </portlet>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-link>User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

and simple view.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetTagServiceUtil"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>
<liferay-theme:defineObjects/>
=========================Testing AssetTagServiceUtil==========================<br>

AssetTag with tag "testglobaltag" count : <%= AssetTagServiceUtil.getTagsCount(scopeGroupId, 10007, "testglobaltag") %><br>
```

I am not able to figure out exactly why It is showing different i.e double than the actual count for roles other than Administrator.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.